# Apache Camel Copying Files from multiple source folders to multiple destination folders

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to camel and we are building an EDI engine and our requirement is to read the files from multiple folders then second step is to parse the message type and the receiver id and based on that the messages need to be routed to different folders.

The source, message type, receiver id and destination cannot be hardcoded in camel instead it should be read from the database and the routes need to be built dynamically.

Please let me know what should be the strategy that we need to follow.

Thanks,
Jayadeep

Comment: You should at least add what have you tried so far, so for other users is easier to help you

Comment: We have tried dynamic router as we well adding routes dynamically but we are not able to programmatically set the destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your comments, you can read from multiple folders by adding routes dynamically but are facing issue when trying to decide on where to send the messages as the destination , headers etc is being read from database.

Here's how I would do it.

Get the file --> Enrich it with database call and get the receiever id etc --> Use Xpath and get the receiver id etc and set them in propertyor header --> Use XSLT and remove the values that you enriched for database call so now you have the original message ---> Now use router and look at properties/headers to decide the `<camel:to>` path

Comment: Thank you Dinesh, i think i understood what I need to do.

Comment: When I am using a content based router how do i set the to from lets say a hashmap. For example      
`code`

/*exchange.getIn().setHeader(stElement.concat(recId),
stElement.concat(recId));*/
header=recId.concat(stElement);
exchange.getIn().setHeader("headerElement",header);


choice().
when(header("headerElement").isEqualTo(stRecIdMap.containsKey(header("headerElement"))))
.to((String)stRecIdMap.get(header("headerElement")))

`code`

Comment: can we set the TO from a hashmap

Comment: The "TO" has to be a "uri". So you can something like this - 
exchange.getIn().setHeader(stElement.concat(recId), stElement.concat(recId));*/
 header=recId.concat(stElement); 
 exchange.getIn().setHeader("headerElement",header);
  choice(). 
     when(header("headerElement").isEqualTo(stRecIdMap.containsKey(header("headerElem‌​ent")))) .to("direct:b")


from("direct:b")
     .....
     ....
     get the header value here
     and do what ever you want